# checked value in php, update query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code which permits me to select a checkbox.. now what i need to do is to give this piece of code a if statement in order that, if it's checked to post a "1" value in the database, otherwise to post 0!

Thanks!

```
echo "<td><input type='checkbox' size='40' name='active[$i] ' value='{$rows['img_active']}' ";?> <?php if($rows['img_active'] == 1) { echo 'checked'; } ?> <?php echo "/>   </td>";
```

Comment: How have you tried to update the data in the database based on this?

Comment: i am going to post the value and then i'll do the query, i mean i intend to post the value given from the checkbox!

Comment: so.. do it ? what your question there exactly ?

Comment: The question is how to modify the input box in order to get different values, if checked or non checked! i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Not checked checkbox value is not sent in POST. At all. So you need to check if there is some value for corresponding image in `$_POST`. And if it is there - than checkboxs is checked on client side. Otherwise - no. And make a decision about what to put into a database based on this.